# Небольшая замена кода

Tags: php, php7.2

Есть код загрузчика фалов на сервер:

```php
  if(isset($_FILES)) {
        $allowedTypes = array('image/jpeg','image/png','image/gif','image/bmp','image/svg+xml','image/tiff');
        $uploadDir = "templates/universal/images/banners/"; //Директория загрузки. Если она не существует, обработчик не сможет загрузить файлы и выдаст ошибку
        for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++)      { //Перебираем загруженные файлы    
        $uploadFile[$i] = $uploadDir . basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
        $fileChecked[$i] = false;
        echo $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]." | ".$_FILES['file']['type'][$i]." — ";
        for($j = 0; $j < count($allowedTypes); $j++) { //Проверяем на соответствие допустимым форматам
        if($_FILES['file']['type'][$i] == $allowedTypes[$j]) {
        $fileChecked[$i] = true;
        break;
```

На openserver проверил все работает, но когда заливаю на сайт там стоит php 7.2 вылазит ошибка

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
> implements Countable in /var/www/

Погуглив узнал что ошибка на строке `for ($j = 0; $j < count($allowedTypes); $j++)` ее как то нужно переделать что бы код работал на новой версии php 7.2

Дальше я бессилен, буду очень признателен если кто найдет минутку на решение этой проблемы.
Спасибо!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php вместо ненужного использования `for`. И ошибка у вас на другой строчке, на этой `$_FILES['file']['name']`. Здесь тоже можно применить `foreach`, но вместо массива может быть пусто. Нужна проверка

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но как должен выглядеть код? Я понятия не имею как правильно его прописать. Скрипт я просто наше в интернет - скачал и на опен сервер запустил но внутри кода я не смыслю. к сожалению. Или это сделать не так просто?